# How property works as a method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We often perform a method to function something like `$('div').show();`. Here the show method would show the div when it is called. But what about `$('div').length;`? The length is the property and not a method but also functions to get the size of the div. So, how the property is called as method? Any new example would be greater for me to make my concept clearer.

Comment: The property is not called as a method. What are you talking about?

Comment: [Click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953047/example-of-properties-vs-methods-in-js) and I will help enlighten you.  Basically, a property (description) is a noun and a function is a verb (action).

Comment: I mean how the length is functioning as it is the property not a function.

Comment: a property key is something that stores a reference to something else.... a function(in case of show) or a value(in case of length)

Comment: could you please illustrate an example.

Comment: There is also .size() in jquery. Anyhow, this is a very interesting question and I would like to learn more. Based on my basic understanding, some languages (OOP) add an attribute (length) to some of their objects types like Java with Arrays cuz they are fixed in size and therefore have a public final length field. But when you implement a Stack of unlimited size, something must manually keep tracking of it's length, so whenever you add to that array, the length variable will become updated.

Comment: But (I'm making an assumption here) that in jquery, the same (worker) that keeps storing the length, is the one that keeps updating it.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery collections are just arrays of elements. The `length` property comes form the array. jQuery updates the length when it's needed. For example, take this **very** simplified version of jQuery:

```
var $ = (function(){

  function jQuery(sel) {
    // an array to hold the elements queried from the DOM
    this.el = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
    // set the length of the array
    // as a property on the current instance
    this.length = this.el.length;
  }

  jQuery.prototype = {
    // a method that does not modify the length
    show: function() {
      this.el.forEach(function(x){
        x.style.display = 'block';
      });
      return this;
    },
    // a method that modifies the length
    parent: function() {
      this.el = this.el.map(function(x){
        return x.parentNode;
      });
      this.length = this.el.length; // update length
      return this;
    }
  };  

  return function(sel) {
    return new jQuery(sel);
  };
}());

$('ul').length; //=> the constructor set up the length
$('ul li').parent().length //=> the parent method updated the length
```

Answer (score 2):

As it was pointed out in the comments below, jQuery's `length` property is not a special property: it's just a regular numeric property on jQuery.  If you want to see proof of that, open up your console window (on a site that has linked jQuery in), and type the following:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor($, 'length')
```

You will see that it's just a regular numeric property.

When you use a jQuery selector, it runs the selector against the DOM and sets the `length` property correctly: no magic there.

However, JavaScript does make it possible to have properties that have `get` and `set` functions, which is pretty nifty functionality.

You can use `Object.defineProperty` for this purpose:

```
var o = {}

Object.defineProperty(o, 'foo', {
    get: function() { return 'bar'; },
    set: function(val) { console.log('setting value to '+val); },
});
```

Then you can call it as if it were a property:

```
o.foo             // returns 'bar'
o.foo = 'baz';    // prints to console
```

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more information.

Here's a silly example that converts color names to RGB strings:

```
Object.defineProperty(o, 'color', {
    get: function() { return this._color; },
    set: function(val) {
        if(val.match(/^#/)) this._color = val;
        switch(val){
            case 'red': this._color = '#f00'; break;
            case 'green': this._color = '#0f0'; break;
            case 'blue': this._color = '#00f'; break;
            case 'white': this._color = '#fff'; break;
            case 'black': this._color = '#000'; break;
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: However, `jQuery.length` is not a "defined" property - it's just a normal property and it's value is set when the jQuery collection set is generated.

Comment: @user2864740 I think you have clear concept about this. Can you explain a bit.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar `jQuery.length` is just a *normal* object property - it has been assigned a number previously. Summarized: `o = {}; o.length = 42; o.length`. Of course it doesn't just assign 42, but rather the size of collection after the `$(selector)` [or whatever] operation, which returns a new jQuery result-set. The reason that `length` (as well as corresponding index-properties) is so that a jQuery object can be used "as" an array-like structure.

Comment: Yes, @user2864740, you're right about jQuery's `length` property...I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Heh.  Thanks for the "sort of" compliment.  I think the OP is actually asking two questions, one of which I failed to answer originally (now corrected): "how does the jQuery `length` property work" and "how can a property behave like a method".  (shrug)  Maybe I missed the point a little bit right off the bat, but hopefully the OP will have a better understanding of things now....