# What does response.on mean? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having trouble with a Node.js http request. (A bigger question I will ask about later if I can't figure it out).

I have code that I modified from and an example and I don't understand what the response.on means. As read more about http in Node.js ([Anatomy of an HTTP Transaction](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/)) I don't see people using examples with 'response.on'. I think I know but I want to clarify. Oh I am using Express.js too.

Thanks

Below is the code I am using to try and call the BART api I need a response from.

```
...
// Real Time Departure from a given station
router.route('/departTimeStation')
.get(function(req, res) {
    vCmd = 'etd';
    vOrig = req.query.vOriginStation;
    vDir = 'n'; // [NOTE] - 'n' or 's', north or south, OPTIONAL
    vPlat = 1; // [NOTE] - 1 to 4, number of platform, OPTIONAL

    var xoptions = {
        host: 'api.bart.gov',
        path: '/api/etd.aspx?cmd=' + vCmd + '&orig=' + vOrig + '&key=' + config.bart.client
    };

    var xcallback = function(response) {

        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            vParsed += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            parseString(vParsed, function(err, result) {
                vShow = JSON.stringify(result);
                vTemp = result;
            });
        });
    };
    http.request(xoptions, xcallback).end();
    return res.send (vTemp)
});
...
```

Comment: It's [this](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`response.on` can take a few 'events' that happen during the `response` life cycle,

The two you have above are `response.on('data'...)` which is when you get the data
and `response.on('end'...)` is at the end of the response, simple as that!

Node Docs on response: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage

Comment: Thank you for that link. I hadn't read the bit of documentation that referred to this.

Answer (score -5):

response.on is a function, or rather method, since it is a property.

Comment: No, methods and properties are different.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953047/example-of-properties-vs-methods-in-js