# What does response.on() method in do in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, request, response

Can anyone please describe to me what is the use of the response.on method in node.js. I am used to it but don't know exactly what is the purpose of it. Just like we used to write #include in our school days even if we don't know what it exactly does we write it on every problem in order to make it a perfect one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659002/what-does-response-on-mean-node-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does response.on mean? Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659002/what-does-response-on-mean-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Node.js HTTP response is an instance of [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter), which is a class that can emit events and then triggers all the listeners for that particular event.

The `on` method attaches an event listener (a function) for a certain event:

```js
response
  .on('data', chunk => {
    // This will execute every time the response emits a 'data' event
    console.log('Received chunk', chunk)
  })
  // on returns the object for chaining
  .on('data', chunk => {
    // You can attach multiple listeners for the same event
    console.log('Another listener', chunk)
  })
  .on('error', error => {
    // This one will execute when there is an error
    console.error('Error:', error)
  })
```

Node.js will call `response.emit('data', chunk)` whenever the response receives a chunk of data, `chunk`. When this happens, all the listeners will run with `chunk` as the first argument. This is the same for any other event.

All the events for a `ServerResponse` can be found in the documentation for [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) and [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) (because responses are also readable streams).

Comment: In the multiple on() listeners above which one happens first or they all happen whenever they are ready?

Comment: @jamespow When the `data` event is emitted, the two listeners are executed in the order that they were added (so the `Received chunk` one would run first followed by the `Another listener` one).