# For JavaScript, how do properties distinguish from methods?

Tags: javascript, methods, properties

In chapter 4 of *Eloquent JavaScript*, it reads: "[Data types, namely, strings] have built in **properties**. Every string value has a number of **methods**. Some very useful ones are `slice` and `index` which resemble the array methods of the same name.

For me, the excerpt that I've cited from Eloquent JavaScript appears to use the terms "property" and "method" interchangeably.

From [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/property/JavaScript), I understand that *"A JavaScript property is a characteristic of an object, often describing attributes associated with a data structure.*

Additionally, [MDN's glossary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Method) defines a method as a function which is a property of an object.

Can anyone assist in distinguishing the terms "property" and "method" (as used in JavaScript) from one another?

Comment: [Example of Properties vs. Methods in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953047)

Comment: Majority of String methods are actually not direct properties since they are part of `String.prototype`. Look at list on left of [`String MDN docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: A method is a property that is a callable function.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**
Property is something "about" the string e.g. its length.
Method is something that can be done to the string e.g. slice